# Prevent partitions from Spotlight indexing each other

Tags: macos, partition, spotlight

I have a single MacBook Pro partitioned into two drives, each running a copy of Mountain Lion. In Partition X, I would like to disable Spotlight from indexing Partition Y. In Partition Y, I want to disable Spotlight indexing of Partition X.

#### Clarification:

Under *System Preferences > Spotlight > Privacy*, setting Partition X to prevent indexing of Partition Y *also prevents Partition Y from indexing Partition Y*. I.e., the privacy settings are preserved across partitions. I am looking for unique privacy settings for each partition.

Comment: Did you find any solution to this? I use macOS 10.12 on one and OS X 10.11 on the other partition, and I've got the very same problem you mentioned in the comment below.

Answer (score 2):

- `System Preferences.. > Spotlight > Privacy`
- Add the mount path you don't want indexed to the list by selecting the device you want excluded also. However, if it's hidden use <kbd>**⌘**</kbd> +<kbd>**⇧**</kbd>+<kbd>**G**</kbd> and enter the path name for example `/Volumes/Partition Y`.

**Note**
After some testing this method does not work with multiple partitions of like OSs (eg. 10.8 on partition A and 10.8 on partition B) but does seem to work if each OS is different. Still not 100% clear on why this is since each drive has it's own `/.Spotlight-V100/VolumeConfiguration.plist` or `/.Spotlight-V100/Store-V1/Exclusions.plist`

Comment: Is that different than selecting the partition from the Finder sidebar?

Comment: No, I clarified my answer, you can also just select it from the sidebar.

Comment: Okay, thanks. That's what I thought you meant. The trouble with this is that the volume is then ignored on the other partition (itself) as well. I want each partition to ignore the other one but index itself.

Comment: yes so in your example when you are booted onto part-X exclude part-Y, when when you boot into part-Y exclude part-X. I have a machine with 4 partitions and different ignore rules for each. that should function, though I'm testing on 2x10.6's, 1x10.7 and 1x 10.9.

Comment: @ele So after a little more tinkering I found as long as you select the mount path e.g. `/Volumes/<partname>` and not `/` it seems to work. in otherwords use the goto folder shortcut and browse to `/Volumes` then select the volume to ignore from there. Hope that works for you. if so I'll fix up the question again.

Comment: I'm afraid it behaves the same way. If I exclude `/Volumes/Macintosh HD 2` from Spotlight while booted into `Macintosh HD`, then `Macintosh HD 2` is still excluded from the Spotlight of `Macintosh HD 2`. Some further research suggests disabling the volumes from mounting at startup.

Comment: Is there any update on this? I have the same issue with a dual boot MacBook (with two physical drives) that has 10.8.x and 10.12.x. When I exclude 10.12.x on the 10.8.x drive, it gets excluded also on the 10.12.x drive itself and vice versa. That seems ridiculous.

Comment: I'm afraid I gave up without ever finding a solution.